# What does difference in ranges of eigenvalues convey?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If there are two matrices **A** and **B**.

The **eigenvalues of A** are in **range 0-80** and **eigenvalues of B** are in **range 0-0.09**.

What can we say about A and B ? Does it make sense to compare A and B based on the difference in ranges ?

Comment: You could say what is the maximal possible determinant for both matrices .. the same about trace..

Answer (score 0):

Let T - operator given by matrix.

In finite dimensional case, the set of eigenvalues is equal the set of scalars P such that operator (T-P*Id) is not reversible. The supremum of set of norms of eigenvalues (in euclidean norm) is called spectral ray of the operator.

So, for example operator B-20*Id is reversible because spectral ray of B is 0.09. However, we don't know if A-20*Id is reversible unless we count eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more elaborately and possibly in layman's terms ? I am not able to connect your answer to my question properly.

Comment: I don't know in which aspect do You want to compare A and B. Determinant? Trace? Etc? What I can say at that moment is that operators given by A and B are not "close" to each other.

Comment: I don't know if this makes sense but let me try explaining. With the same case I explained in the question, let there be C = f(A,B). Since I already know that the eigen value range of B is comparatively smaller than eigen value range of  A, can I comment something like A contributes to C more than B ?